# Can multiple users utilise the same Amazon WorkSpace

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

I am looking at AWS Workspaces for some kiosk-style PCs. We have shift workers, so in a single day there might be 3 different people using the workstation.

Can I have a single AWS workspace and share it for 3 different users? They would not be using it concurrently.

Comment: Yes. But they have to use the same workplace user credentials. Maybe you can have a service user and share the same credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remote desktop on AWS Workspaces. It means one user per workspace. Multiple users cannot use one machine.

Comment: Any reference to this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, basically it's a VDI , and using Amazon client anyone who have ad account and has registration ID can access the workspaces.
Even RDP will work if you enable inbound RDP port on workspace security group, but for RDP your workspace should be running.